# Is there an easy way to add arguments with values to python3 cmd.Cmd?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Is there an easy way to add arguments with values to `python3`'s [`cmd.Cmd`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/cmd.html)?**

For example, it's easy to implement commands with simple parameters:

```
> action1 param1 param2
```

by adding `do_action1()` and `complete_action1()`, to complete I can search the list of existing parameters.

But how would you implemented parameters with values, for example:

```
> action1 param1=234 param2=SomeTextValue
```

or

```
> action1 param1 234 param2 SomeTextValue
```

where `param1` would be set to `234` and `param2` to `SomeTextValue`.

Can this be parsed by `cmd.Cmd`?

I can think only about getting the whole argument list in `do_action1( self, params = None )` and then parse it myself.

If I use `optparse` the parameters would have to be prefixed with dash like `-p` or `--param1` and `--param2`, so to get completion in `cmd.Cmd` I would have to type 2 dashes first ...

```
> action1 --param1=234 --param2=SomeTextValue
```

If I have to manually parse the parameters is there any python3 module like `optparse` which does not expect the parameters to have 2 dash prefix?

Any suggestions?

Comment: @LennartRegebro in my case they don't make sense, thanks for your concerns though ... I was asking if there is a similar package, how do you know what I'm building and what standards to apply?

Comment: This question was very confusing. Also I've never heard of anyone using `cmd` before this, I had to look it up! :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `cmd.Cmd` doesn't actually do a whole lot of parsing for you, anyway. So, yes, you can handle parameters with arguments simply by completing parameters with a trailing `=`, and parsing the commands yourself:

```
import cmd

def parse(arg):
    return tuple(k.partition('=') for k in arg.split())

class MyShell(cmd.Cmd):
    def do_foo(self, arg):
        for x, _, y in parse(arg):
            print(x, y)

    def complete_foo(self, text, line, begidx, endidx):
        # Cmd treats = as the end of params; we don't want that.
        if line.endswith('='):
            return ()

        opts = ['param1=', 'param2', 'param3=']
        return [opt for opt in opts if opt.startswith(text)]

MyShell().cmdloop()
```

Example usage:

```
(Cmd) foo param<TAB>
param1=  param2   param3=  
(Cmd) foo param1=a param
param1=  param2   param3=  
(Cmd) foo param1=a param2 param3=ah
param1 a
param2 
param3 ah
```

Note that our completions contain a trailing `=` as a hint to the user, to let them know a parameter can be passed.